# Conversion failed while converting datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

[image]

Query:

```
UPDATE dbo.FinalExtract
SET WEWE = CASE 
              WHEN Wait_time <= '24' 
                 THEN CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(hour, -24, Wait_time)) 
                 ELSE CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(hour, +24, Wait_time)) 
           END
```

This is what I want but I'm getting a conversion error

Let me tell you `wait_time` is

```
wait_time = CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(Hour, time_created, time_responded) % 24) + '.'
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(minute, time_created, time_responded) % 60)
```

Output is : `19.07`

I want to add +24 hours if output value is less than 24 hours and if output value is more than 24 hours then an add extra 24 hours.

I tried this

```
UPDATE dbo.FinalExtract
SET WEWE = CASE 
              WHEN Wait_time <= '24' 
                 THEN CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(hour, -24, Wait_time)) 
                 ELSE CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(hour, +24, Wait_time)) 
           END
```

but it's not working I'm getting conversion error.

Comment: please post your table schema, sample data and expected result

Comment: yeah i have uploaded screenshot ... where i want to update Column WEWE values

Comment: plz friends i m getting error if i execute this query   .....Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: why you want to add  +/- 24 ?, is it the date range to cover whole day ? share screen shot of the error or send error text.

Comment: yeah bro, the logic behind this is... when in time_created a time_responded period falls in weekend then add 24 hours extra to the wait_time and if its fall in weekdays then substract 24 hours

Comment: What type is WEWE ?

Comment: WeekENDWeekEnd its varchar becoz i need value in this format eg. 19.27

Comment: I'm not at all clear on what you're trying to do here. Some sample data and *expected results* would probably help a lot - the sample data ideally as text, ideally ideally as `INSERT` statements (rather than an image, since we don't need typing practice). Also, all of your existing sample data spans a few hours on a single day but apparently you want to do different things depending on single day/multiple days, so the sample should ideally include that also.

Answer (score 0):

The time part should have a colon. Your wait_time should be

```
wait_time = CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(Hour, time_created, time_responded) % 24) + ':'
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(minute, time_created, time_responded) % 60)
```

Comment: i did that... i m getting wait_time in varchar format, coz of which i m not able to execute this query... UPDATE dbo.FinalExtract
SET WEWE = case when Wait_time <='24' then convert(varchar, dateadd(hour, -24, Wait_time)) else convert(varchar, dateadd(hour, +24, Wait_time)) end    ......as this is showing conversion error

Comment: i tried this ..................UPDATE dbo.FinalExtract
SET WEWE = IIF ( 
  wait_time <= 24, dateadd(hour, -24, Wait_time), dateadd(hour, +24, Wait_time) )
 but again i m getting error Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0.2' to data type int.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you:

```
Declare @timeCreated datetime='2016-06-09 12:26:12.000'
Declare @timeresponded datetime='2016-06-09 14:28:12.000'
declare @waittime datetime;
set @waittime=(select case when DateDiff(hh,@timeCreated,@timeresponded)   <   24 then DateDiff(hh,@timeCreated,@timeresponded) + 24else DateDiff(hh,@timeCreated,@timeresponded) end)
update dbo.finalextract set wewe=@waittime
```